# Firebase REST API key management

Tags: api, authentication, firebase, jwt

I have some data stored on firebase which I want to expose to some people/apps through the **REST API** provided by firebase. I want to make a key management system so that only people who have a key can access the database through the API. I'm thinking of using the custom authentication mentioned here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html

The JWT would be the API key. 
Is this a good idea or is there a better way to do this?
Also, how can I make it so that the key will no longer be usable after a certain time (e.g a few months or a year)

I'd appreciate your opinions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [Firebase documentation on token generation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-token-generation):

> By default, authentication tokens expire 24 hours after they are issued and the client will automatically be unauthenticated at that time. You can override this by changing the session length setting under the Login & Auth tab of your App Dashboard, or individually when creating the token by providing a specific expiration date. For details, see the docs for the specific token generator library you're using.

The specifics of setting a token-specific expiration vary from library to library. For [Java](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-java) it requires calling `setExpires(Date)`, for [Node.js](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-java) it requires settings a timestamp in the `requires` property, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Frank. can you please tell me if you think its a good idea to do this or should I use an API management tool like Apigee.

Comment: Recommending a specific technology is off-topic here on StackOverflow, since it attracts opinionated answers and leads to a lot of discussion. Pick the technology that you feel comfortable with and see if it works.

Comment: My apologies I only mentioned Apigee as an example. I just want a simple way of managing access to the database. What I meant was do you think an API management tool would be a better option or would it just be faster and simpler to use firebase tokens.